# Assign a cluster to an object in R

Tags: r, object, hclust

What's the easiest way to assign a cluster to a group in R?
The functions utilized are:

> hclust and cutree.

Basically, I want to assign one of the clusters created under cutree to an object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cutree` gives you a vector of cluster indices

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests))
clusters.idx <- cutree(hc, k = 5) # create five clusters

head(clusters.idx)
#    Alabama     Alaska    Arizona   Arkansas California   Colorado 
#          1          1          1          2          1          2
```

which you can use to `split` your original data:

```
clusters <- split(USArrests, clusters.idx)
```

Here, `clusters` is a list of data.frames. You can for example access the first cluster using `clusters[[1]]`.